# Is it practically possible to shorten computer Bits?

Tags: computer-building, numbering

A couple of days ago, I came up with an idea to shorten bits.

First (for 7-digit bit-data, e.g. "1000000"), if the second number of "1000000" is "0", make it "x", otherwise (if it is "1") make it "y".

The second number of the 7-digit binary-digits is called the "identifier separator".

Everything after the identifier separator "counts" (++) e.g.

"1000000" -> "x0"
            
^

"1000001" -> "x1"
          
^

"1000011" -> "x2"
         ^

etc.

So, the result looks like this:

```
1000000 -> x0
1000001 -> x1
1000011 -> x2
1000111 -> x3
1001111 -> x4
1011111 -> x5

1100000 -> y0
1100001 -> y1
1100011 -> y2
1100111 -> y3
1101111 -> y4
1111111 -> y5
```

But of course, all computers can read is 1s (on) and 0s (off).

Is there a way to use x's and y's for storage / something?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the notation you are using? Your original idea does not make sense.  There is already hexadecimal notation that is widely used. Your original idea is extremely confusing and honestly does not make sense. This is coming from a person with multiple college degrees in engineering and computer science.

Comment: Reducing 8-bit bytes to 7-bit bytes is hardly original.

Comment: I made it up myself, as a way of shortening 7-digit binary computer bits. But all computers can read is 1s and 0s, so I'm asking if there is a way of shortening bits, or if my idea can be used for something else.

Comment: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15512/did-any-computer-use-a-7-bit-byte/15514 No you didn't.

Comment: I did do it, I made it up when I was doing testing in an editor, and shortened it by 2 million bits.

Comment: this is off topic. I'd suggest it would be better suited to computer ("computing") science or math stacks, but frankly they will just shut it down as it is cranky

Comment: There's not much too it, I just thought it would be a good idea for other things such as storage, etc. I just came here to ask if it was possible.

Comment: These 7 bits shall henceforth be known as - up, left, odd, quirk, cheese, gromit & wheelbarrow.

Comment: Data compression uses a form of this.  Nothing new.  A binary bit takes up 1 bit, but could occupy 32 bits (depending on processor and compiler).

Comment: Here is a bit `0`  - Now I am shortening it to `o` - see its much shorter now.  :D

Comment: how would you express 10101010? also, note that unless you can create hardware that can process more than low/high signal (which is where 0 and 1 come from) you would just have to translate that data into binary to process it anyway, which would be a big drag on efficiency at processing time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But of course, all computers can read is 1s (on) and 0s (off).

> Is there a way to use x's and y's for storage / something?

> All of this is my original idea.

and comment

> I just thought it would be a good idea for other things such as storage, etc

Well, it is, but it is not an original idea at all.

This is basically what SSD manufacturers did when they transitioned from SLC (single level cell) capable of storing `0` or `1` to MLC (multi level cell) capable of storing `0`, `1`, `x`, `y` in each NAND call, then to TLC capable of storing 8 different values and now even QLC capable of storing 16 different values in each location.

Before SSDs, this concept of a non-binary "signal constellation" was widely used in modems and radio.

The concept in information theory is named "channel coding", and was already [undergoing theoretical analysis back in 1928 by Hartley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem), then Claude Shannon predicted exactly how much information you could transmit in a given frequency range using multi-level signals.

---

If instead you reduce the number of bits needed to store a message while using the same two binary symbols (`0` and `1` typically although their names don't matter), then you are dealing with *compression*, which is also a very mature field in information theory.  But your question clearly introduced new symbols.

Comment: Good, short explanation.